# Not restart animation to root controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, quartz-core

I have an animation that starts to the first controller, when I call this controller from another, the animation does not start.
This is my `HomeController.m`:

```
//
//  HomeController.m
//  /

#import "HomeController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "HomeController.h"
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface HomeController (){
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *accendi;
// create the label animated
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *arrow;
// create the image animated

@end

@implementation HomeController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated];

[self frecciaanimata];

}
-(void) frecciaanimata {

    CGRect arrowFrame = self.arrow.frame;
    arrowFrame.origin.x = arrowFrame.size.height;

    CGRect accendiFrame = self.accendi.frame;
    accendiFrame.origin.x = accendiFrame.size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                          delay:1.2
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{
                         _arrow.frame = CGRectMake(140, 244, 14, 28);
                         _accendi.frame = CGRectMake(80, 247, 63, 21);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
//create animation block
                     }];
 }


// end of animation block
@end
```

Can I make to start my animation when the other controller calls this controller (`HomeController`), by pushing a button?

Comment: try to move [self frecciaanimata] in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

Change the `[self frecciaanimata];` to :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(frecciaanimata) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
```

**Update:**

for the recent request of handling the animation when hitting back from backGround, do the following:

in your `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(someMethod)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Then add the `someMethod` as follows:

```
-(void) someMethod{
    [self performSelector:@selector(frecciaanimata) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];

}
```

Comment: an other question, the animation not start when returning from background. help me please?